# How to simulate data and visualize in a single R function

Tags: r, function, data-visualization, simulation, distribution

I'm using `replicate` to simulate distributions in R and visualize how they change with different parameters (e.g., `rbinom(100,1,0.5)` vs. `rbinom(100,1,0.01)`).

I'd like to do all of this within a single function that 1. simulates replicates, 2. sets the plotting dimensions and parameters, and 3. loops through and draws density curves.

In separate pieces, this code works no problem:

```
n <- 100
d <- as.data.frame(
    replicate(n, 
              expr = rbinom(n, 1, 0.5), 
              simplify = F)
)
colnames(d) <- 1:n
plot( NULL, xlim = c( min(d)-0.5, max(d)+0.5), ylim = c(0,2)) 
for(i in 1:n) lines( density( d[,i]) )
```

But inside a function, only a single density curve is returned:

```
plotcurves <- function(n, distr, ymax) {

    d <- as.data.frame(
        replicate(n, 
                  expr = distr, 
                  simplify = F)
    )
    colnames(d) <- 1:n
    plot( NULL, xlim = c( min(d)-0.5, max(d)+0.5), ylim = c(0,ymax)) 
    for(i in 1:n) lines( density( d[,i]) )
}

plotcurves(n = 100, distr = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5), ymax = 2)
```

The solution seems like it would be very simple but I cannot seem to find it. 
What do I need to do to fix the code OR does a function like this already exist that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your function, `distr` is *evaluated* before it reaches the call to `replicate`. You can see this if you make a variation of the function that just returns the data frame `d` instead of plotting it:

```
show_d <- function(n, distr, ymax) 
{
    d <- as.data.frame(
        replicate(n, 
                  expr = distr, 
                  simplify = F)
    )
  return(d)
}

show_d(n = 3, distr = rbinom(5, 1, 0.5), ymax = 2)
#>   c.1L..0L..1L..1L..1L. c.1L..0L..1L..1L..1L..1 c.1L..0L..1L..1L..1L..2
#> 1                     1                       1                       1
#> 2                     0                       0                       0
#> 3                     1                       1                       1
#> 4                     1                       1                       1
#> 5                     1                       1                       1
```

You'll notice the columns are all the same. Effectively, the call to `rbinom` was evaluated *then* passed to `replicate`, which is the same as calling `replicate(3, c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1))`. So you *are* plotting all the lines - it's just that the lines are all the same.

What you need to do inside a function is to ensure that `distr` is passed as a **call** to `replicate` rather than being evaluated and sent as a vector. You can do this using `match.call()` and extracting the third element (which is the second parameter):

```
plotcurves <- function(n, distr, ymax) {
    mc <- match.call()[[3]]
    d <- as.data.frame(
        replicate(n, 
                  expr = mc,
                  simplify = F)
    )
    colnames(d) <- 1:n
    plot( NULL, xlim = c( min(d)-0.5, max(d)+0.5), ylim = c(0,ymax)) 
    for(i in 1:n) lines( density( d[,i]) )
}

plotcurves(n = 100, distr = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5), ymax = 2)
```

[image]